# What is time complexity of slice in scala?

Tags: scala

What is time complexity of scala slice method? Is it `O(m)` or `O(n)`, 
where m is number of elements in slice and n is number of elements in collection.

More specific question: what is time complexity of 
`someMap.slice(i, i + 1).keys.head`, where i is random int less than someMap.size? If slice complexity is `O(m)` then it should be `O(1)`, right?

Comment: This will depend on the implementation. On a list, for example, plain old lookup is `O(n)`, so it's not possible to slice in `O(m)`.

Comment: On List, there is a better bound O(until) (actually  O(max(n, until))) which may be way faster than O(n) if your slice is close to the start of the list though. You don't care how long the list is after your slice. But that's not O(m), which is until - from. You pay to get to the start of the slice too.

Comment: @DidierDupont Big-O notation is always a worst case analysis. To say that it's `O(max(n, until))` implies it's `O(n)` if `until <= n`.

Comment: Sorry, it is of course O(_min_(n, until)), which is indeed better than O(n) most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This clearly depends on the underlying datatype. Slicing an `Array`, `ArrayBuffer`, `ByteBuffer`, or any other sub-class of [`IndexedSeqOptimized`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L110) for example is `O(k)` if you're slicing `k` elements from the container. `List`, for example, is `O(n)` you can see by its [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L240). You'll likely want to check the source for your specific type.

`Map` gets its implementation of slice from [`IterableLike`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L109). From the implementation pasted below, it's clearly the cost to iterate over elements in the collection plus the cost to create a newly built map.

For `TreeMap` this should be `O(n + k lg k)` if you're slicing `k` elements out of the map.

For `HashMap` this should be bounded by `O(n)`.

```
override /*TraversableLike*/ def slice(from: Int, until: Int): Repr = {
  val lo = math.max(from, 0)
  val elems = until - lo
  val b = newBuilder
  if (elems <= 0) b.result()
  else {
    b.sizeHintBounded(elems, this)
    var i = 0
    val it = iterator drop lo
    while (i < elems && it.hasNext) {
      b += it.next
      i += 1
    }
    b.result()
  }
}
```

When in doubt, look at the source.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't quite sure how it is implemented. In addition, slice is O(n) due to drop O(n) complexity.

Comment: @ChelovekChelovechnii Slice is not `O(n)` in general. To rephrase `IterableLike.slice(...)` is the cost to iterate over the elements + the cost to build a new container of `k` elements. The iterating portion consists of the `drop` and the while loop. That is `O(from) + O(k)` which is bounded by `O(n)`. Note that `drop` on `IndexedSeqOptimized` is `O(1)`.

Comment: I don't get it! There is a while loop in the source code of slice for Array, how can it be O(1) ?

`var i = lo
    while (i < hi) {
      b += self(i)
      i += 1
    }
    b.result()`

Comment: @林鼎棋 You're right, that's wrong. It's not O(1) it's O(k) for IndexedSeqOptimized subtypes.